# Which column is prioritized in MySQL for unique constraint errors?

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints, unique-constraint

Lets say I have 2 varchar columns `first_name` and `last_name` (both have unique constraints on them - not together but separately). So every person in my database has a unique `first_name` and a unique `last_name`.

Now, If I try to insert `Donald` `Trump` into the database when there is already a conflict for both columns (either another `Donald` `Trump` or `Donald` `Diaz` and `Scott` `Trump`).

Does anyone know which column would MySQL scream out that there is a conflict in? `first_name`? `last_name` or would it tell me both in the exception?

Comment: I don't think it's defined. What difference does it make?

Comment: It would *scream* for the first one it finds the conflict for, and I *think* that order is defined by the order of index definition. But like @Barmar wrote - why would that matter? When you think about it, it's really irrelevant and makes no difference for the actual end result.

Comment: To the best of my recollection, indices are checked in the same order they are defined, so the first to _scream_ would be the first to be find as being violated, when they are checked in the pre-defined order. Having said that, I'm puzzled about the background of this question (as suggested by the previous commentators).